# What does the phrase "contender bracket" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "contender bracket" in the following sentence from the description of the app "Rowdy City Wrestling":

> You can Work your way up through the Rowdy City Wrestling **contender
> bracket** by facing opponents in boisterous one-on-one bouts and
> multiperson rumbles.

Here is a description of the app from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stencyl.rowdycitywrestling&hl=hi&gl=US):

*In career mode you will start as a nobody and fight your way towards the RCW World Championships. It's not going to be an easy journey, you will fight in 1 vs 1 matches, six person brawls and royal rumble events. The aim of the game is to earn cash to improve your stats so you can take on the guys at the top.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bracket) of 'bracket' is "a group with fixed upper and lower limits". For example, people are often divided into '*age brackets*' or '*income brackets*'.

In some sports like wrestling, players are categorised into 'brackets', perhaps by their size, weight, strength or gender. Players compete against others that fall into the same 'bracket'. There may be other kinds of defined 'brackets' that divide up contestants in such sports.

Comment: Interesting. Is the term used plausibly in the quote in the question or has it being misused as a meaningless buzzword?

Comment: @David42 I'm not at all familiar with 'Rowdy City Wrestling', but I don't see any misuse, assuming that there are other brackets after 'contender'.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States tournaments use a form of tree diagram called a bracket to display who is going to play who with a view to determining the eventual winner. The term is unknown in the UK where we call it the draw. So in the example the contender makes their way up the tree by winning games.

More detail with diagrams is available in the [Wikipedia entry on bracket (tournament)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(tournament))